# How to design model with hierarchical relationship table using EF?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

If I have 4 tables with a hierarchical structure such as:

1. building (Building have many floors. 1F, 2F, 3F..) - level 1
2. floor (Floor have many rooms too. 101, 201, 301..)  - level 2
3. room (Room have many amenities too. PC, room cooler..)  - level 3
4. amenity  - level 4

Here my model concept:

building model

```
public class Building
{
    [Key]
    public string BuildingId { get; set; }
    public string BuildingName { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Floor> floors { get; set; }    
}
```

Floor model

```
public class Floor
{
    [Key]
    public string BuildingId { get; set; }
    [Key]        
    public string FloorId { get; set; }
    public virtual Building Building { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Room> rooms { get; set; }
}
```

Room model

```
public class Room
{
    [Key]        
    public string BuildingId { get; set; }
    [Key]
    public string FloorId { get; set; }
    [Key]
    public string RoomId { get; set; }
    public virtual Building Building { get; set; }
    public virtual Floor Floor { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Amenity> amenities { get; set; }
}
```

Amenity model

```
public class Amenity 
{
    [Key]
    public string AmenityId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Builiding")]
    public string BuildingID{ get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Floor")]
    public string FloorID{ get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Room")]
    public string RoomID{ get; set; }
}
```

Is that correct and is there anything more I need?

I tried this [ASP.NET tutorial](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc) all day but it's too simple to understand and express my concept because I am not good with C# syntax or .NET.

Answer (score 0):

Looks great, What else you would be doing.  At the end of the day you will be using some database and it seems perfect structure from database point of view. Go ahead.

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I would use NoSQL database such as MongoDB.

It does not use **Table** but it uses **Collection** which is similar to each other.

The benefit of using Collection is it can contain arrays or

another JSON objects inside of JSON objects.

It can contain even JavaScript functions and arrays.

Also many different rooms can have different kinds of keys and values because

MongoDB is **schemaless!**

**Example: Collection "building"**

```
{
  name: 'buildingName',
  floor: [
    '1': [
      'room1': {
        'amenity': [ 'door', 'toilet', 'bed', 'window' ]
      },
      // ...
    ],
    // ...
  ], // ...
}
```

By this design, you can accomplish what you need with MongoDB.